# Be able to access the direcrory but show error in $PATH

Tags: path

When I enter the `$PATH` in terminal in Debian 11, it outputs `/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux: No such file or directory` at the end, but I can enter `/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux#`  by `cd` command. So, why there is that error?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you use `$PATH` as a command? What is it you _want_ to do when you use `$PATH` as a command?

Comment: @Kusalananda I guess the ouput should not contain `No such file or directory`.

Comment: It's still unclear what you want to do, whether you are using the special  `PATH` variable as an ordinary variable, and what this variable's value is. The error message that you get is completely reasonable and expected, depending on what the variable's value is.

Comment: @Kusalananda I once think `No such file or directory.` is an error. Was I right?

Comment: Entering `$PATH` as a command is an error.  The shell complaining about a strange command not being found is an appropriate response to that. Again, _what it is that you want to achieve_?

Comment: @Kusalananda Why entering `$PATH` as a command is an error? I want to see the content of the ***path*** by entering `$PATH`.

Comment: To see the contents of the `PATH` variable in `bash`, use one of `declare -p PATH` (it will also display additional info relevant to what type of variable `PATH` is), `echo "$PATH"`, or `printf '%s\n' "$PATH"`.  Please note that none of the quotes can be left out.

Comment: @Kusalananda But why entering `$PATH` as a command is an error?  I am still not understand it.

Comment: Entering `$PATH` as a command is an error, just like entering any arbitrary `:`-delimited string as a command is an error. `$PATH` is just a list of directory pathnames with `:` between them. Using that as a command makes no sense.  What do you want to do?

Comment: @Kusalananda I just want to see the contents of `echo $PATH` Will `$PATH` try to execute the contents of `echo $PATH`, which cause an error?

Comment: I was _very careful_ with saying that none of the quotation marks in the commands that I gave to you could be left out. The command you want to use is therefore `echo "$PATH"`.  This command will display the contents of the `PATH` variable. There will be no error from executing that command. All that will happen is that the `$PATH` string (the contents of the `PATH` variable) will be printed. This command is mentioned at the top of the answer that Ljm Dullaart gave you.

Comment: @Kusalananda  Okay. I know now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter `$PATH` as a command in the terminal, it will expand to the contents of `$PATH` and try to execute that. You can see the exact contents of `$PATH` with

```
echo "$PATH"
```

`$PATH` contains a list os directories where executables may be found, separated by a `:`. Trying to execute that list will fail, as there is no executable file with that name.

The `$PATH` that you have is bizar, and not standard on Debian 11.  A`PATH` is generally more something like

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

I suspect that you are not giving the complete output, because, if `PATH` contained just a single directory, `bash` would complain with

```
bash: /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux: Is a directory
```

Because the `PATH` contains directory names, you can `cd` to the directories.

--edit--

Since you added your exact `PATH`, try

```
ls /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/li/Downloads/sh:/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/li/.local/bin:/home/li/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux
```

That will also give the same error message. It is because a list of directories is not the same as a single file.

Even `cd` will not work. Try to

```
cd /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/li/Downloads/sh:/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/li/.local/bin:/home/li/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux
```

That too will give you the error.

A list of directories is not a single directory.  A list of directories is also not a single file.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. All the output is `bash: /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/li/Downloads/sh:/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/li/.local/bin:/home/li/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux: No such file or directory
`. May you help me check where is wrong?

Comment: @Y.zeng To help you with what's wrong, you would have to explain what you want to do.  Also, what you show in your comment here is not the same as in the question. Now we don't know which one is correct and can't trust either of them.